# Testing Django Admin Action (redirecting/auth issue)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I'm trying to write tests for an Admin action in the `change_list` view. I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026779/testing-custom-admin-actions-in-django) but couldn't get the test to work. Here's my code and issue:

```
class StatusChangeTestCase(TestCase):
"""
Test case for batch changing 'status' to 'Show' or 'Hide'
"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.categories = factories.CategoryFactory.create_batch(5)

    def test_status_hide(self):
        """
        Test changing all Category instances to 'Hide'
        """
        # Set Queryset to be hidden
        to_be_hidden = models.Category.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
        # Set POST data to be passed to changelist url
        data = {
            'action': 'change_to_hide',
            '_selected_action': to_be_hidden
            }
        # Set change_url
        change_url = self.reverse('admin:product_category_changelist')
        # POST data to change_url
        response = self.post(change_url, data, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(
            models.Category.objects.filter(status='show').count(), 0
           )

    def tearDown(self):
        models.Category.objects.all().delete()
```

I tried using `print` to see what the response was and this is what I got:

```
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/admin/login/?next=/admin/product/category/">
```

It seems like it needs my login credentials - I tried to create a user in `setUp()` and log in as per Django docs on testing but it didn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you need to create a user and then log in the test client. Please show what you tried and what happened.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks! I re-tried it (after getting some sleep) and realised I wasn't instantiating django's `Client` class, thus the login wasn't persisting in my subsequent requests. Thanks for pointing my in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - I wasn't instantiating Django's `Client()` class when I created a superuser, so whenever I logged in - it didn't persist in my subsequent requests. The correct code should look like this.

```
def test_status_hide(self):

    """
    Test changing all Category instances to 'Hide'
    """

    # Create user
    user = User.objects.create_superuser(
        username='new_user', email='test@example.com', password='password',
    )

    # Log in
    self.client = Client()
    self.client.login(username='new_user', password='password')

    # Set Queryset to be hidden
    to_be_hidden = models.Category.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)

    # Set POST data to be passed to changelist url
    data = {
        'action': 'change_to_hide',
        '_selected_action': to_be_hidden
        }

    # Set change_url
    change_url = self.reverse('admin:product_category_changelist')

    # POST data to change_url
    response = self.client.post(change_url, data, follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(
        models.Category.objects.filter(status='show').count(), 0
        )
```

Comment: If you use Django's test case class (`from django.test import TestCase`) then you can use `self.client` without instantiating it yourself.